# Timeout Errors on an UpdatePanel skip Appliation_Error - how do I capture them?

Tags: asp.net, exception, timeout, updatepanel

Working with some legacy code that has a great many UpdatePanels.  We are experiencing problems where some postbacks to UpdatePanels are timing out (exceeding the default 90 second limit), and I want to know when this happens.

We are currently logging all unhandled exceptions in Global.asax.cs::Application_Error.  If I manually throw in an error in a postback on the update panel, this is captured just fine.  If I drop in a Thread.Sleep(100 * 1000), I will *not* see anything in Application_Error, but on the client I will see:

```
Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 
        An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. 
        The status code returned from the server was: 500
```

From what I can tell, it is the server layer throwing the error, not the application itself, and so we will never see anything hit Application_Error.  Is that correct?

Also, are there any options for actually capturing/logging this error, aside from noticing it in the client, and then doing another POST operation back to log it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches that I know of:

```
Server-side:
protected void ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)  
{
    ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage = "An error occurred during the request: " + e.Exception.Message; 
}

Client-side:
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Subscribe to the end request event of the update panel
    function pageLoad()  {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(onEndRequest);  
    }

    // You can of course have this emit the error information to whatever control you want, I made up the Label1 object for demonstration purposes
    function onEndRequest(sender, args)  {
        var lbl = document.getElementById("Label1");
        lbl.innerHTML = args.get_error().message;
        args.set_errorHandled(true);
    }
</script>
```

Here is some documentation:

[Customizing Error Handling for ASP.NET UpdatePanel Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx)

[Error Handling Customization for ASP.NET UpdatePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32569/Error-Handling-Customization-for-ASP-NET-UpdatePan)

Comment: Your first example, AsyncPostBackErrorMessage, will not capture these timeout errors.  That was the last thing I tried before posting my question... it'll catch any other regular exception, but it appears that the method being called by the postback in the update panel continues to run and finish normally, while the server says "hey, this took too long, here's a 500 error"

Comment: I ... think so.  Actually, in this case it's IISExpress on my local box.